# using header location inside switch case

Tags: php, header, location

I have

```
$CID = $_REQUEST ['cid'];
$UID = $_REQUEST ['uid'];

if ($UID == '0') {
    header ( 'Location: url/you-need-to-log-in-before-redirect/' );
} else {

    switch ($CID) {
        // go to URL1 case number is the same as CID
        case "147" :
            header ( 'Location:  url' . $UID );
            break;
        case "148" :
            header ( 'Location: url' . $UID );
            break;
        default :
            echo "Something went terribly wrong";
    }
}
```

Is this ok? I have a problem of $UID registering as blank which should not be possible as it is always set to be 0 for non-registered users and for registered it's unique. should i use exit() instead of break? or both? Or should i not be using header loaction at all to send users forward...i have hundreds of cases inside this switch case statement. i cant post any actual urls so the 'url' in example is not a variable but just a placeholder for the actuall full address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the zero's type integer? If yes your condition is wrong, because it tests for string but you have an integer.

Try: `if ($UID == 0) {` and the same for the switch cases.

Comment: the $UID and $CID are both integers and i send them to .php file in question via ?cid=xxxxx&uid=yyyyy.

Comment: when i store the values in $CID and $UID at the first two lines aren't they stored as integers even if i use the $_reguest?